# On closing one jframe window other windows close automatically why?

Tags: java

I am working on swing based application after log-in i have a menu window containing different tabs which open different windows but when i close one of them close all windows automatically.Guide me how to solve it? thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: i use only dispose because net-bean drag and drop automatically set setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` so your whole application will close when this window is closed. This is because (as it says below) `System.exit();` will be called.

You should pass one of the other values to `setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation)` depending on the needs of your application.

In any case please read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) if you are using multiple frames.

---

Source [setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)

> public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation)
>
> Sets the operation that will happen by default when the user initiates
>   a "close" on this frame. You must specify one of the following
>   choices:
>
> - `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything;    require the program to handle the operation in the
>     windowClosing    method of a registered WindowListener object.
> - `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
> - `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener
>     objects.
> - `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.
>
> The value is set to HIDE_ON_CLOSE by default. Changes to the value of
>   this property cause the firing of a property change event, with
>   property name "defaultCloseOperation".

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should use HIDE_ON_CLOSE.  If you would like to open the frame again you could do:

```
mainFrame mF = new mainFrame();
mF.setVisible(true);
```

mainFrame being the name of the GUI class.